# Make a search function

Tags: android

I want to make a search function to my android app. I want the things that you are going to search from in the app, not a database or something like that! :) So yeah, maby someone could link me a tutorial or something? :)

Thanks! (REALLY sorry for bad english!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at this tutorial:

[searching employees](http://coenraets.org/blog/android-samples/androidtutorial/)

and this [one](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#SearchingYourData) from android developer site